# What Will Happen To Google Analytics Code Appearing Before The Head?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm looking at a site right now which has some Google Analytics code in an unusual place, namely before the `<head>` tags.

The Analytics all seems to be working correctly...but what would the expected behaviour for this be?

Would the JS be loaded instantly, before even the title? If so, what implications (if any) would that have for how things are tracked?

More broadly, what is expected behaviour for all kinds of JavaScript placed outside both `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

Any advice much-appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with modern browsers is that they don't require valid HTML.

And nowadays tags are parsed as they are encountered without strict checking. So any script (or any tag element, for that matter) that is before the `<head>` section but still within the `<html>` section is treated as part of the `<head>` section of the document, and whatever is present in the `<head>` tag in the document is kept in `<head>` if only valid tags are present, and is pushed to `body` if text or invalid tags are found.

Such scripts, as long as they do not reference the `<head>` tag will be fine (since the head tag has changed now). This is the *normal, but unexpected* behaviour, and can change between browsers and even their versions. As browsers evolved they began to accept files and structures deviating from strict standards. You can verify this by using the Developer Console (F12) in Chrome on this document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('title'));
</script>
<head>
    <title>This</title>
    as
    <script>var s="sastra";console.log(s);
    </script><title>This2</title>
    as
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://google.com">Click here for Google</a>
        <p> How are you?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and calling `document.getElementsByTagName('html')` and viewing their `head` and `body` elements and comparing it with the source. In the same document above, if the 2 'as' are removed from within the `<head>` section,

I mean this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('title'));
</script>
<head>
    <title>This</title>
    <script>var s="sastra";console.log(s);
    </script><title>This2</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://google.com">Click here for Google</a>
        <p> How are you?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

you will see that the `head` and `body` are now different using the same Developer Console. See, I told you *unexpected* behaviour.

Nowadays tags are identified based on context and browsers have no trouble rendering something like `<html><title>TitleHere` which violates a lot of rules. Try for yourself!

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: this is incorrect - the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags are inferred when missing. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5641997/501771

Comment: @Timothy003, yes they are inferred, but when you yourself write `<head>` tags, along with tags not inside `<head>` tags, different browsers interpret it differently and produce unexpected behavior whereby it cannot exactly be predicted what will uniformly happen across browsers. That is what I've mentioned here. Do you refer to my statement where I say "invalid HTML"?

Comment: it's actually quite predictable - [from the spec:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead) "When the user agent is to apply the rules for the "in head" insertion mode, the user agent must handle the token as follows: [...] ↪A start tag whose tag name is 'head'; ↪Any other end tag: Parse error. Ignore the token." your answer suggests that the `<head>` tag is still parsed but you can't reference it in the script; this is not true. the parser inserts a `<head>` tag for you and ignores the one you write

Comment: also, you can't have non-metadata in the head. the parser will treat `<head><title>TitleHere</title>text<script></script>` as `<head><title>TitleHere</title></head><body>text<script></script>`, because it thinks you omitted the `<body>` tag

Comment: You can add to the answer, might help more than the comments

Answer (score 1):

The javascript will still load as long as it doesn't reference the "head" in the load code.

e.g. head load: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683376/94668

```
<script>
var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "yourfile.js";
    script.async = true; //asynchronous
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

e.g. script code (which google analytics uses): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#quickstart

```
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

basically look for the `getElementsByTagName(elementString)` and make sure elementString !== 'head'.